# how much did the trip cost the school

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The 200 seventh graders at John Witherspoon Middle School raised 80%
>   of the funds needed for a field trip. The school donated the remaining
>   20%. When they went to purchase the tickets, however, they were given
>   a 10% bulk rate discount after a $ 20 processing fee. Faced with an
>   unexpected surplus the students chose to buy each member of the class
>   one cookie and were still left with 18 dollar, which they gave to the
>   bus driver. If each of the cookies cost 0.30 dollar, how much did the
>   trip cost the school?

I solved this problem as follows-

Cost for cookies= 60 * 0.3 = 200
Tips to Bus Driver = 18

Total (Cookies + Bus Driver) = 78
If total cost for the school is x then, $x-.90x-20 = 78$

$\Rightarrow$ x= 980

Cost of school= .20*980 = 196

What is wrong in my approach? Correct answer is given as 160!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the total amount of money contributed by students and the school as follows;

- 200 students contributed $0.8 x$,
- the school contributed $0.2x$,
- $\$$18 is the remaining amount they gave to the driver,
- $\$$20 processing fee for purchasing ticket,
- 10% discount earned for purchasing the tickets,
- $(x-20)0.9$ the money used for purchasing the tickets.

Therefore to solve for $x$, the following applies:

\begin{align}
[x-(x-20)0.9+20]-60&=18 \\
x-[0.9x-18+20]-60&=18 \\
x-0.9x+18-20-60&=18 \\
0.1x-62&=18 \\
\end{align}

Therefore $x= \$800$.  Since the school contributed 20%, the dollar amount contributed by the school towards the trip is $0.2\cdot 800=\$160$.

Comment: Your answer, as originally written, was quite difficult to follow due to the poor formatting.  I have attempted to clean it up.  For future reference, please read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use MathJax to write mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The 10% discount is given *after* a $\$20$ processing fee. So $78 = (x-20)*0.1 = 0.1x - 2$. What you said is equivalent to $78 = 0.1x - 20$.